# Multiply (a)(b) function possible?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I have an oddball of a question from a code quiz. They expect me to write a function that multiplies (a) and (b) but instead of writing it like:

```js
  multiply(a,b) {
    return a*b;
  }
```

They expect me to do the math with:

```
    multiply(a)(b)
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: this is called currying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a function that returns another function.

```js
const multiply = a => b => a * b;
console.log(multiply(4)(3));
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they'd like you to use currying. Currying allows you to reduce functions of more than one argument to functions of one argument. The link below has a very similar example to what your employer is looking for.

Helpful Resource: 
https://blog.benestudio.co/currying-in-javascript-es6-540d2ad09400

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a function that returns a function

```
function multiply (a) {
  return function (b) {
    return a * b;
  };
};

console.log(multiply(4)(3));
```